# DatePicker is so laggy compose

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, android-jetpack-compose

i have a problem, my DatePicker is so laggy and i dont know why. It is laggy in all time, even when i change composable to calendar screen. Here is code:

```
//Main box
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color(0xff162232))
) {
    //State for date picker
    val datePickerState = remember {
        DatePickerState(
            yearRange = (2024..2041),
            initialSelectedDateMillis = sharedVMCalendarMainScreens.selectedDate,
            initialDisplayMode = DisplayMode.Picker,
            initialDisplayedMonthMillis = null,
        )
    }

    //Update date in main and calendar screens
    val chosenDate = convertMillisToDate(datePickerState.selectedDateMillis!!)
    sharedVMCalendarMainScreens.updateChosenDate(chosenDate)
    sharedVMCalendarMainScreens.updateSelectedDate(datePickerState.selectedDateMillis!!)

    DatePicker(
        state = datePickerState,
        colors = DatePickerDefaults.colors(
            selectedDayContainerColor = Color(0xff85aff7),
            todayDateBorderColor = Color(0xff85aff7),
            todayContentColor = Color(0xff85aff7),

        )
    )
}
```

I tried to delete this lines of code:

```
//Update date in main and calendar screens
val chosenDate = convertMillisToDate(datePickerState.selectedDateMillis!!)
sharedVMCalendarMainScreens.updateChosenDate(chosenDate)
sharedVMCalendarMainScreens.updateSelectedDate(datePickerState.selectedDateMillis!!)
```

but it did not work. Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried a release build? The performance tends to be considerably better.

Comment: @Philio yes, of course i tried, but it did not help